# How to get the URL of the page new user?

Tags: url

I know that's a completely newbie question but, i want to navigate to "New user" and i can't because i get an infinite url like

> lightning/setup/ManageUsers/page?address=%2F005%2Fe%3FretURL%3D%252F005%253FisUserEntit.....

There is anyway to change it or parse it?

PS: I have a dev account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to navigate to "New user" record form then use below URL:-

want to navigate to "New user" url:-

> /lightning/o/User/new

Here **o** represents the object and **User** represents the User object and **New** tells to create  new form of User record.

Comment: Thanks mate! That's so much more than i expected but works like a charm.

Comment: Sorry i've to ask cause i can't find it. Where i can get this info from Salesforce? To now how to update, delete... Rest Api dev guide?

Comment: If this is LWC I would recommend using `navigateToNewRecordPage()` as seen on the following link (which is more future proof): https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_page_types